# DataSet.WriteXml to string

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I'm tring to get a string from a DataSet *without* using GetXml. I'm using WriteXml, instead. How to use it to get a string?
Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
string result = null;

using (TextWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    dataSet.WriteXml(sw);
    result = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, this fails on really large datasets (like it does on GetXML())  System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)

Comment: VB.Net Version:
`Dim sw As IO.StringWriter = New IO.StringWriter()`
`dataset_name.WriteXml(sw)`
`Dim result As String = sw.ToString()`

Answer (score 9):

Write to a [`StringWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx), and then call `ToString` on that.

Note that if you want the generated XML declaration to specify UTF-8 instead of UTF-16, you'll need something like my [`Utf8StringWriter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955611/xmlwriter-to-write-to-a-string-instead-of-to-a-file/955698#955698#).

Answer (score 1):

here is the vb.net code:

```
 Private Function GenerateXML(ByVal ds As DataSet) As String
    Dim obj As New StringWriter()
    Dim xmlstring As String
    ds.WriteXml(obj)
    xmlstring  = obj.ToString()
    Return xmlstring 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

public string ConvertDatatableToXML(DataTable dt)

```
        MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
        dt.WriteXml(str, true);
        str.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str);
        string xmlstring = "";
        xmlstring = sr.ReadToEnd();
        return (xmlstring);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).