# XmlTextWriter serialization problem

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I'm trying to create a piece of xml. I've created the dataclasses with xsd.exe.
The root class is `MESSAGE`.

So after creating a `MESSAGE` and filling all its properties, I serialize it like this:

```
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xsd.MESSAGE));
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(sw, response);
string xml = sw.ToString();
```

Up until now all goes well, the string xml contains valid (UTF-16 encoded) xml.
Now I like to create the xml with UTF-8 encoding instead, so I do it like this:

**Edit**: forgot to include the declaration of the stream

```
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xsd.MESSAGE));
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    serializer.Serialize(xtw, response);
    string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

And here comes the problem: Using this approach, the xml string is prepended with an invalid char (the infamous square).
When I inspect the char like this:

```
char c = xml[0];
```

I can see that c has a value of 65279.
Anybody has a clue where this is coming from?
I can easily solve this by cutting off the first char:

```
xml = xml.SubString(1);
```

But I'd rather know what's going on than blindly cutting of the first char.

Anybody can shed some light on this? Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955611/xmlwriter-to-write-to-a-string-instead-of-to-a-file/955698#955698

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's your code modified to not prepend the byte-order-mark ([BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)):

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xsd.MESSAGE));
Encoding utf8EncodingWithNoByteOrderMark = new UTF8Encoding(false);
XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter(stream, utf8EncodingWithNoByteOrderMark);
serializer.Serialize(xtw, response);
string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

Comment: `XmlTextWriter` has been [deprecated by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx), so nowadays I would do `var xtw = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = utf8EncodingWithNoByteOrderMark });` instead.

Answer (score 7):

65279 is the Unicode byte order mark - are you sure you're getting 65249? Assuming it really *is* the BOM, you could get rid of it by creating a UTF8Encoding instance which doesn't use a BOM. (See the constructor overloads for details.)

However, there's an easier way of getting UTF-8 out. You can use `StringWriter`, but a derived class which overrides the `Encoding` property. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955611/xmlwriter-to-write-to-a-string-instead-of-to-a-file/955698#955698) for an example.

Comment: I ran the code and got 65279, too.  Probably a typo in the question.

Comment: I don't find creating a new class necessarily *easier*... what I would find easier is that I could *set* the Encoding of a StringWriter without having to derive from it.

Comment: @fretje: Yes, but deriving a new class is easier than changing the .NET framework :) And the point about deriving a new class being easier than using XmlTextWriter is that you only have to do it in one place, ever.

Comment: @Jon: Agreed. I'll take this approach if I ever need this a second time in the same project ;-)