# Deserializing SQL varbinary in form of XML to C# byte[]

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, arrays, xml-deserialization

I'm working on a small proof of concept project, in which the client sends an image file in a `byte[]` format and the server inserts the data to the database in `Image` column, which is `VarBinary(MAX)`. This part works fine, however, I'm having issues trying to convert the data back into a byte array and sending it to the client.

In the database, there is a stored procedure which is responsible for getting data and returning it in XML:

```
SELECT 
    ...
    asset.Image AS 'Image'
FROM ASSETS AS asset
WHERE asset.Id = @Id
FOR XML PATH('Asset')
```

A sample query result looks like this (the actual value for `Image` is actually a lot longer than this, but I shortened it to make it more readable):

```
<Asset>
  ...
  <Image>/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wB</Image>
</Asset>
```

And in the code, I have a generic method which deserializes this XML into its corresponding object:

```
internal static T ExecuteQuery<T>(StoredProcedures storedProcedure, ParameterList parameters)
    {
        using (var connection = GetSqlConnection())
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(storedProcedure.ToString(), connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameter.Key.ToString(), parameter.Value));
                }

                connection.Open();

                var data = command.ExecuteScalar();

                return DeserializeXml<T>(data.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The `Asset` type (which is what I'm passing it to this generic method has several properties, one of which is `Image`:

```
public class Asset
{
    public Asset()
    {
    }

    ...

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement("Image")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I execute the program, I get this error:

```
 There is an error in XML document
```

It seems like the deserializer is having issues with the `VarBinary` value (it used to work fine before I added this `Image` property). Any ideas why this could be happening? Do I need to use a memory stream to convert the data back?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at how you are saving the XML to the database.  XML de-serialization will fail if the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is being saved with the XML to the database (which is usually the case, depending on how you're doing it).

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969941/xmltextwriter-serialization-problem) on how to eliminate the byte order marks when saving XML data to the database.

Comment: I'm not saving the XML to the database, I'm just returning an XML from the database. Take a look at my stored procedure.

Comment: I realize that, but at some point the XML was inserted into the database.  If it was inserted with the BOM, you will have a problem when you attempt to retrieve it.

Comment: The XML was never inserted into the database, it was generated from the columns in a stored procedure call and is returned.

Comment: Ah, okay gotcha, my bad then