# QBXML: Simple CustomerAdd "error when parsing"

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbxml

I've built a very simple XML request to QuickBooks Desktop and validated it with the QBSDK qb*XML Validator, which tells me the XML instance is valid:

```
<?qbxml version="12.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <CustomerAddRq requestID="12">
      <CustomerAdd>
        <Name>EDWARDS, JOHN</Name>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      </CustomerAdd>
    </CustomerAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

However, both my own C# app and the SDK-provided qbXML Test apps fail with the unhelpful message "QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream."

I've successfully authorized the app through QuickBooks, and gave it that extra customer information permission just to be sure.

According to the OSR, the only required field is "Name". I've run out of places to go with this investigation.

Is there anything obviously wrong with how I'm going about this? Is there a permissions issue I'm not seeing?

Comment: Worked for me.  What year/version of QB are you running against? Try running against a test company.

Comment: @WilliamLorfing Interesting. I'm running against QB Pro 2013, and I've got a test company set up. I can run a CustomerQueryRq successfully. "EDWARDS, JOHN" is not in my customers list, so I don't think it's a collision problem. I'm not sure what the deal is here...

I lifted this XML straight out of what my app is ready to sent to QuickBooks.

Comment: Got it! C#'s XDocument.ToString() drops the <?xml?> directive. My other query worked because I was using XmlDocument.InnerXml, which didn't do that (but looked uglier compared to XDocument). I went ahead and just concatenated: doc.Declaration.ToString() + doc.ToString().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! C#'s XDocument.ToString() drops the `<?xml?>` directive. My other query worked because I was using XmlDocument.InnerXml, which didn't do that (but looked uglier compared to XDocument). I went ahead and just concatenated:

```
doc.Declaration.ToString() + doc.ToString()
```

Basically the same problem as [XDocument.ToString() drops XML Encoding Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228976/xdocument-tostring-drops-xml-encoding-tag)