# Convert xml document to string with encoding as utf-8

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

I want to create an xml document and save it in string object.

I have refer both these question on SO for saving and encoding purpose

- [XDocument.ToString() drops XML Encoding Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228976/xdocument-tostring-drops-xml-encoding-tag)
- [Force XDocument to write to String with UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871738/force-xdocument-to-write-to-string-with-utf-8-encoding)

My code :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("BANKID",
       new XElement("ReqID", "WEB"),
       new XElement("ReqHeader", "CASHDEP"),
       new XElement("CurrencyCode", ""),
       new XElement("CurrencyAbbrivation", "")));

using (TextWriter writer = new Utf8StringWriter(builder)) // Error Line
{
doc.Save(writer);
}
builder.ToString();

public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }        
}
```

It gives me error saying "Utf8StringWriter does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

**How to modify that class which would accept arguments as `StringBuilder` ?**

Comment: Similar to: [stackoverflow Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871738/force-xdocument-to-write-to-string-with-utf-8-encoding)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom `Utf8StringWriter` class has no constructor accepting a parameter, but you're trying to pass a value to it. That's why you're getting the error message.

Add a public constructor that accepts a `StringBuilder`, then pass it on to the base class:

```
public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public Utf8StringWriter(StringBuilder stringBuilder)
        :base(stringBuilder)
    {
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding { get { return Encoding.UTF8; } }
}
```