# How to add Namespace and Declaration in XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am creating xml in C#, and want to add Namespace and Declaration . My xml as below:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://ab.com//abc";

XDocument myXML = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0","utf-8","yes"),
    new XElement(ns + "Root",
        new XElement("abc","1")))
```

This will add `xmlns=""` at both Root level and child element abc level as well.

```
<Root xmlns="http://ab.com/ab">
    <abc xmlns=""></abc>
</Root>
```

But I want it in only Root level not in child level like below:

```
<Root xmlns="http://ab.com/ab">
    <abc></abc>
</Root>
```

and how to add Declaration at Top, my code not showing Declaration after run.

Please help me to get the complete xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Root xmlns="http://ab.com/ab">
    <abc></abc>
</Root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same namespace in your child elements:

```
XDocument myXML = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0","utf-8","yes"),
        new XElement(ns + "Root",
            new XElement(ns + "abc", "1")))
```

If you just use `"abc"` this will be converted to an `XName` with no Namespace.  This then results in an `xmlns=""` attribute being added so the fully qualified element name for `abc` would be resolved as such.

By setting the name to `ns + "abc"` no `xmlns` attribute will be added when converted to string as the default namespace of `http://ab.com/ab` is inherited from `Root`.

If you wanted to simply 'inherit' the namespace then you wouldn't be able to do this in such a fluent way.  You'd have create the `XName` using the namespace of the parent element, for example:

```
 var root = new XElement(ns + "Root");
 root.Add(new XElement(root.Name.Namespace + "abc", "1"));
```

Regarding the declaration, `XDocument` doesn't include this when calling `ToString`.  It will if you use `Save` to write to a `Stream`, `TextWriter`, or if you supply an `XmlWriter` that doesn't have `OmitXmlDeclaration = true` in its `XmlWriterSettings`.

If you wanted to just get the string, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228976/xdocument-tostring-drops-xml-encoding-tag) has an answer with a nifty extension method using a `StringWriter`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i dont want to refer namespace in child element then how to implement ?

Comment: @user1893874 there's no easy way, I've added a possible option.  How you apply this depends on the wider context of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the namespace on all elements you create:

```
XDocument myXML = new XDocument(
                  new XDeclaration("1.0","utf-8","yes"),
                  new XElement(ns + "Root",
                     new XElement(ns + "abc","1")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. cant i add namespace only to the Root element ?