# XML to String value

Tags: xml, vb.net

I use an XMLWriter to manually make an XML document. Is there a way to put that in string form so I can write it to my DB?

I am coding in VB.Net

Comment: The code you have so far would be a good start. Also - what database system do you use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955611/xmlwriter-to-write-to-a-string-instead-of-to-a-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it write to a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder():
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
{
    // write the xml
}

string writtenXml = sb.ToString();
```

In VB.NET:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb)
    ' write the xml '
End Using

Dim writtenXml As String = sb.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have have your XmlWriter wrap a StringWriter.  Then you process it as you already are.   when you want to access the string itself call StringWriter.ToString().