# Powershell: Convert XML to String

Tags: xml, string, powershell, converters

I am searching for a way to convert a XML-Object to string.

Is there a way like $xml.toString() in Powershell?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You are probably looking for `OuterXml`.

`$xml.OuterXml` should give you what you want.

Comment: This worked for me too.  The only problem is I lose the whitespace formatting in the transition.  Any ideas on how I can either preserve or add nice tab formatting?

Comment: Try `$xml.PreserveWhiteSpace = $true`

Answer (score 10):

How are you creating the XML object?

Typically, if you want an XML string from an object, you'd use:

```
$object | ConvertTo-Xml -As String
```

Comment: I start the XML-Object this way:
[XML]$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><somestuff></somestuff>';

While the script is running i append a lot of information to this object.


At the end i need this XML-File to be a string, just like '<somestuff><node></node></somestuff>'

Comment: If you need it to be a string, don't make it XML.  Start with a here-string, and append to that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[string[]]$text = $doc.OuterXml #or use Get-Content to read an XML File
$data = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
[void] $data.Add($text -join "`n")
$tmpDoc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDataDocument
$tmpDoc.LoadXml($data -join "`n")
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
$writer = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($sw)
$writer.Formatting = [System.Xml.Formatting]::Indented
$tmpDoc.WriteContentTo($writer)
$sw.ToString()
```

I used this script to write my generated XML into a TextBox in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version:

```powershell
[string]$outputString = $XmlObject.childNode.childNode.theElementValueIWant.ToString()
```

Xml path is whatever your source XML tree structure is from the `$XmlObject`.

So if your `$XmlObject` is:

```xml
<xmlRoot>
  <firstLevel>
    <secondLevel>
      <iWantThisValue>THE STRING I SEEK</iWantThisValue>
    </secondLevel>
  </firstLevel>
</xmlRoot>
```

you would use:

```powershell
[string]$outputString = $XmlObject.firstLevel.secondLevel.iWantThisValue.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **PowerShell 7+**, there is a very simple way to pretty-print XML using [`XElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?view=net-6.0):

```
$xmlNode = [xml] '<foo x="42" y="21"><bar>baz</bar></foo>'
[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::Parse( $xmlNode.OuterXml ).ToString()
```

Output:

```text
<foo x="42" y="21">
  <bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
```

As the original poster of the [C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55426127/7571258) wrote, it's not the most efficient way in terms of memory usage and execution time. Also you don't get much control over the formatting, e. g. I didn't find a way to print attributes on new lines. If these things are important to you, the `StringWriter` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58745841/7571258) would be more appropriate.