# Reading from memory stream to string

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, memorystream

I am trying to write an object to an Xml string and take that string and save it to a DB. But first I need to get the string...

```
    private static readonly Encoding LocalEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    public static string SaveToString<T> (T settings)
    {
        Stream stream = null;
        TextWriter writer = null;
        string settingsString = null;

        try
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream();

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            writer = new StreamWriter(stream, LocalEncoding);

            serializer.Serialize(writer, settings);

            var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

            stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            
            settingsString = LocalEncoding.GetString(buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // If the action cancels we don't want to throw, just return null.
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();

            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }

        return settingsString;
    }
```

This seems to work, the stream gets filled with bytes. But when I come to read it back into the buffer and then into the string... the buffer is filled with '0'! Not sure what I doing wrong here guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get a string from a MemoryStream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181/how-do-you-get-a-string-from-a-memorystream)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you'd checked the results of `stream.Read`, you'd have seen that it hadn't read anything - because you haven't rewound the stream. (You could do this with `stream.Position = 0;`.) However, it's easier to just call `ToArray`:

```
settingsString = LocalEncoding.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

(You'll need to change the type of `stream` from `Stream` to `MemoryStream`, but that's okay as it's in the same method where you create it.)

Alternatively - and even more simply - just use `StringWriter` instead of `StreamWriter`. You'll need to create a subclass if you want to use UTF-8 instead of UTF-16, but that's pretty easy. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/955698/22656) for an example.

I'm concerned by the way you're just catching `Exception` and *assuming* that it means something harmless, by the way - without even logging anything. Note that `using` statements are generally cleaner than writing explicit `finally` blocks.

Comment: Thanks :) . That's quick work. I know the using blocks are more usual. But I quite like the flatness this gives me, no nested usings. Which is only a style thing. I didn't know there was a StringWriter, seems much easier, but I like the ability to specify the encoing. I'll probably add an overload for this, rather than a new class.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars: How exactly are you intending to add an overload to `StringWriter` itself? The point of the new class is that `StringWriter` always returns UTF-16 from its `TextWriter.Encoding` property; the extra class just overrides that property.

Comment: sorry, my wording was confusing. I will add an overload to my own method to specify the encoding.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars: Right, that's fine. You'll still need to add the extra `StringWriter` class, but that's just to *use* within the method.

Comment: I have just finished your book... and someone up voted this today. I had forgotten You had answered this. Amazing coincidence. Also, "C# in Depth" is the BEST language book I have ever read, amazing stuff.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars: Very glad you enjoyed it :)

Answer (score 44):

```
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fs.ToArray());
```

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some the essential explanation to the answer here.

Comment: What is `stem` here? If a variable, how did you you instantiate it? Same question for `fs`.

Comment: The user has mistakenly used stem instead of System

Answer (score 14):

```
string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((stream as MemoryStream).ToArray());
```

Comment: I would question the use of `as` here - it's not protecting you from anything. Firstly, you know the stream is a `MemoryStream` anyway, plus, even if it wasn't, passing `null` into `GetString` will throw an exception, so you may as well use an explicit cast in the first place.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 8):

In case of a very large stream length there is the hazard of memory leak due to [Large Object Heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap). i.e. The byte buffer created by stream.ToArray creates a copy of memory stream in Heap memory leading to duplication of reserved memory. I would suggest to use a `StreamReader`, a `TextWriter` and read the stream in chunks of `char` buffers.

In netstandard2.0 `System.IO.StreamReader` has a method [ReadBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readblock?view=netstandard-2.0#System_IO_StreamReader_ReadBlock_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Int32_)

you can use this method in order to read the instance of a Stream (a MemoryStream instance as well since Stream is the super of MemoryStream):

```cs
private static string ReadStreamInChunks(Stream stream, int chunkLength)
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string result;
    using(var textWriter = new StringWriter())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var readChunk = new char[chunkLength];
        int readChunkLength;
        //do while: is useful for the last iteration in case readChunkLength < chunkLength
        do
        {
            readChunkLength = reader.ReadBlock(readChunk, 0, chunkLength);
            textWriter.Write(readChunk,0,readChunkLength);
        } while (readChunkLength > 0);

        result = textWriter.ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

NB. The hazard of memory leak is not fully eradicated, due to the usage of MemoryStream, that can lead to memory leak for large memory stream instance (memoryStreamInstance.Size >85000 bytes). You can use [Recyclable Memory stream](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2015/02/06/announcing-microsoft-io-recycablememorystream/), in order to avoid LOH. This is the relevant [library](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream)

Comment: Yes - use StreamReader - but not because of memory leaks, but because it's just the best way to do it!