# XmlTextWriter has newline character always

Tags: c#, xml, line-breaks, xmltextwriter

I'm serializing an object using the `XmlTextWriter` and I'm doing a `ToString` on the created XML structure. I have the following as my settings:

```
settings.Indent = true;
settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
```

When I open the produced XML in Textpad or Notepad++, I get to see that \r\n is always present. Is this some text rendering issue or is that a character that will always be present? If so I find it unusable! How can I get rid of those \r\n and still have my XML indented and formatted when I do a `ToString`?

Here is a sample from the produced XML!

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<dealProfiles\r\n   xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\r\n  <num>76376</num>\r\n  <time>sometime</time>\r\n
```

Comment: how do you call `ToString()`? Still not clear on which object you call the ToString method.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/a/955618/1160780. You need to create a StringWriter, and pass that to the XmlWriter.