# How to control the encoding while serializing and deserializing?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm using serialization to a string as follows.

```
public static string Stringify(this Process self)
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Process));
  using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
  {
    serializer.Serialize(writer, self,);
    return writer.ToString();
  }
}
```

Then, I deserialize using this code. Please note that it's not an actual stringification from above that's used. In our business logic, it makes more sense to serialize a **path**, hence reading in from said path and creating an object based on the read data.

```
public static Process Processify(this string self)
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Process));
  using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(self))
    return serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Process;
}
```

}

This works as supposed to except for a small issue with encoding. The string XML that's produced, contains the addition *encoding="utf-16"* as an attribute on the base tag (the one that's about XML version, not the actual data).

When I read in, I get an exception because of mismatching encodings. As far I could see, there's no way to specify the encoding for serialization nor deserialization in any of the objects I'm using.

**How can I do that?**

For now, I'm using a very brute work-around by simply cutting of the excessive junk like so. It's Q&D and I want to remove it.

```
public static string Stringify(this Process self)
{
  XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Process));
  using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
  {
    serializer.Serialize(writer, self,);
    return writer.ToString().Replace(" encoding=\"utf-16\"", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: See this existing answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/955698/67392 You can override the encoding that `string`/`StringWriter` assume.

Comment: Another option could be to use `DataContractSerializer` and `OnSerializing` attribute http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/06/wcf-extensibility-serialization-callbacks.aspx