# XmlWriter encoding UTF-8 using StringWriter in C#

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8, xmlwriter

I'm using C# to output an xml file and Im trying to set the xml encoding value to UTF-8 but its currently outputting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

This is my code:

```
public sealed class StringWriterWithEncoding: StringWriter {
    private readonly Encoding encoding;

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding) {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding {
        get {
            return encoding;
        }
    }
}

private string GetXml(JobStore jobStore) {
    StringWriterWithEncoding sw = new StringWriterWithEncoding();
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    settings.Indent = true;
    using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings)) {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement("resources");

        writer.WriteStartElement("string");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("name");
        writer.WriteCData("value");
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

Must be something simple I am missing?

Comment: Can you share your code on .NETFiddle?

Comment: `Utf8StringWriter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955611/xmlwriter-to-write-to-a-string-instead-of-to-a-file/955698#955698) should work.

Comment: Your code does not compile -- `StringWriterWithEncoding` does not have a parameterless constructor.  Or, maybe the version you are actually does have a parameterless constructor which leaves `encoding` at its default (null) value, meaning `Encoding` returns null?  That would explain your problem.  Anyway, if I do `StringWriterWithEncoding sw = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.UTF8);` everything works correctly.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JxACgB).

Comment: Life saver! Thanks a million man!

Comment: Please do not get into the habit of adding "ASAP" begging to your questions - the volunteers in our community [will answer at leisure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495). Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your code does not compile -- `StringWriterWithEncoding` does not have a parameterless constructor.  Or, if it does have a parameterless constructor, maybe it actually looks like this?

```
public sealed class StringWriterWithEncoding : StringWriter
{
    private readonly Encoding encoding;

    public StringWriterWithEncoding() { }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding)
    {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return encoding; }
    }
}
```

If so, that would explain your problem - the field `encoding` has been left at its default (null) value, meaning `Encoding` returns null, and so no encoding will appear in the XML file.

To fix it, eliminate the parameterless constructor, and do:

```
var sw = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.UTF8);
```

Or change the parameterless constructor to explicitly set `Encoding.UTF8`:

```
public sealed class StringWriterWithEncoding : StringWriter
{
    private readonly Encoding encoding;

    public StringWriterWithEncoding() : this(Encoding.UTF8) { }

    public StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding encoding)
    {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return encoding; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Just use the output file name for the XmlWriter instead of the StringWriterWithEncoding:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    Indent = true
};

using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(filePathName, settings))
{
    ...
```

Comment: Even this this, the XML header is still `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`

Comment: This does not work. XML header encoding still utf-16

Comment: Doesn't work because the encoding is overwritten by the encoding set on the stringwriter.